# How to add border radius to a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add border radius to my container but can't get it to work for me.

```
Container(
   color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
   height: 400.0,
   width: 500.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
   ),
   child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
   ),
),
```

[image: Console error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error that you are receiving is that whenever you have a decoration for a container you need to make sure that color parameter is in the decoration instead of just the container. Below I have changed your code to not produce that error message, if you are still having issues getting the border radius to work after this change let me know!

```
Container(
   height: 400.0,
   width: 500.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
       color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
   ),
   child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have decoration property in the container, you are supposed to pass the color within the decoration and not the container directly.

```
Container(
//Not allowed color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
height: 400.0,
width: 500.0,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50], //place it here
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
),
child: SvgPicture.asset(
 'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Container(
height: 200.0,
width: 300.0,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
color: Colors.green[50],
),
child: AssetImage(
'assets/images/index.png',
),
),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).